Python strptime not working when time zone is PST
I have a python function to convert a given date time string to epoch time. It is working when the date time string has the time zone, say IST. I need to change the time zone to PST/PDT for obvious reasons, but it throws ValueError: time data '01-06-2024 21:30 PDT' does not match format '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M %Z'
#!/usr/bin/python3

def convertTime(dateStr):
    from datetime import datetime
    import pytz
    
    dateFormat = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M %Z"
    naiveDateTime = datetime.strptime(dateStr, dateFormat)
    # tTimezone = pytz.timezone("Asia/Kolkata")
    tTimezone = pytz.timezone("America/Los_Angeles")
    localizedDateTime = tTimezone.localize(naiveDateTime)
    epochTime = int(localizedDateTime.timestamp())

    # return epochTime
    print(epochTime)

# convertTime("01-06-2024 21:30 IST")
convertTime("01-06-2024 21:30 PDT")

As I said, If I use "01-06-2024 21:30 IST" and tTimezone = pytz.timezone("Asia/Kolkata"), it just works. Any way the the PDT date time can be converted to epoch?

This question is similar to: How to preserve timezone when parsing date/time strings with strptime()?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

When I switch to tTimezone and call to convertTime to IST, I get a similar error: ValueError: time data '01-06-2024 21:30 IST' does not match format '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M %Z'

from the datetime docs strptime() only accepts certain values for %Z: 1) any value in time.tzname for your machine’s locale, 2) the hard-coded values UTC and GMT

...and it gives the example: So someone living in Japan may have JST, UTC, and GMT as valid values, but probably not EST. It will raise ValueError for invalid values.". Add print(time.tzname) to your test and everyone can see what works for them.

The %Z specifier is extremely limited.  From the documentation:

strptime() only accepts certain values for %Z:


any value in time.tzname for your machine’s locale


the hard-coded values UTC and GMT


So someone living in Japan may have JST, UTC, and GMT as valid values, but probably not EST. It will raise ValueError for invalid values.

When you think about it, it makes sense that this wouldn't work because time zone IDs aren't unique around the world.  For example, CST could mean:

Central Standard Time USA
China Standard Time
Cuba Standard Time

I suggest handling the time zone identifier outside of strptime entirely, using a table of the time zones you actually care about.
import zoneinfo
zone_dict = {
    'PST': zoneinfo.ZoneInfo('America/Los_Angeles'),
    'PDT': zoneinfo.ZoneInfo('America/Los_Angeles'),
    'MST': zoneinfo.ZoneInfo('America/Denver'),
    'MDT': zoneinfo.ZoneInfo('America/Denver'),
    'CST': zoneinfo.ZoneInfo('America/Chicago'),
    'CDT': zoneinfo.ZoneInfo('America/Chicago'),
    'EST': zoneinfo.ZoneInfo('America/New_York'),
    'EDT': zoneinfo.ZoneInfo('America/New_York')
    }
zone_id = dateStr.split()[-1].upper()
tzinfo = zone_dict.get(zone_id)
# ...
localizedDateTime = naiveDateTime.replace(tzinfo=tzinfo)

